# Binding Opacity values to a static property;

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to make a desktop overlaying application (Think rainmeter) and because backgrounds can change, I want to be able to change the general colors and alpha values for text in the application.

So In a settings menu I want a slider that OnValueChanged sets a Property in a static class and lots and lots of controls have their Opacity bound to that Property. To make this extra complicated (maybe?) the application has multiple windows open simultaneously. I have little experience with binding and can't get it to work.

My Code so far:

VisualSettings.cs

```
namespace ProjectSideBar
{
    public  class VisualSettings
    {
        public static double Opacity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ProjectSideBar.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:PSB="clr-namespace:ProjectSideBar"
        Title="MainWindow"  Height="1080" Width="300" ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStyle="None" Closing="Window_Closing_1" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Background="Transparent"  >
    <Window.Resources>
        <PSB:VisualSettings x:Key="VisualSettings"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="ClockTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="22:22:22" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="84" Width="300" Cursor="None" Foreground="White" FontSize="48" FontFamily="BatmanForeverAlternate" TextAlignment="Center" Opacity="{Binding Source={StaticResource VisualSettings} , Path=Opacity}" Margin="0,22,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1.5"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>


        <Slider x:Name="TestSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,1052,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.611" Width="172" Foreground="#FF122268" ValueChanged="TestSlider_ValueChanged" LargeChange="0.1" SmallChange="0.01" Maximum="1" Value="0.65"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void TestSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    VisualSettings.Opacity = TestSlider.Value;

}
```

Can someone help me out?

Kind Regards, RoXaS

Comment: This link [here](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties) will get you started.

Comment: @RohitVats Thanks, Works perfectly. If you add this as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind with static properties using **`x:Static`** but issue with x:Static is that they don't support property changed mechanism i.e. if static property changes, it won't be updated on UI.

However, with WPF 4.5 you have support for that by using event **`StaticPropertyChanged`**. You just need to ***make sure whenever static property changes you raise this event so that UI gets updated.***

Also the syntax for binding static properties is bit different like this in your case:

```
"{Binding Path=(local:VisualSettings.Opacity), Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Sample can be found [**here**](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties).